# Adding AddRazorRuntimeCompilation() to the container in .NET CORE 6 will break the CSS footer

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I create a brand new ASP.NET Core MVC project using VS 2022 and .NET Core 6.
VS will generate the base template and when I run it without touching any code, everything is fine.

[image]

So far so good.

Now I add the NuGet dependency *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation* version 6.0.0.

In *Program.cs* file, I add a line

```java
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(); //Add this line of code
var app = builder.Build();
```

Rebuild the program and run it. Now I see the footer is not at the bottom of the page anymore.

Is it a bug or did I do something wrong here?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you have this problem in a local development environment?

Comment: Yes, it is in local environment (localhost).

Answer (score 9):

I was struggling the same problem as well,
while trying the versions of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` nuget package and found the solution with **5.0.13** version.

If you downgrade the package from 6.0.1 to 5.0.13, the problem goes away and footer will be on bottom again.

Comment: Tried this with high hopes, but it didnt work unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

What is happening is that when you enable runtime editing, the .NET Core built in bundle and minification is removed.  If you look at `shared/_layout.cshtml`, there is a `_layout.cshtml.css` file.  This is the runtime bundle/include you are missing.  Since this is your core layout, move the contents from this file to your `wwwroot/css/site.css` file and the footer and other elements will render as before.

Comment: What if you have this problem with a css that you do not want to apply to the `wwwroot/css/site.css` file? Is there a way to use `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()` and keep the isolated css working?

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2022, there's an option for `hot reload on file save`.  this fixed my issue without having the need to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation`

Comment: Working on JetBrains Rider which has no hot reload, so I'm forced to use `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()`

Answer (score 2):

Is it your intention to actually use [RazorPages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)? It looks like you just want to add runtime compilation to the standard MVC views.

If you intend to use controllers and views, just add:

`builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`

But, I tried your code as well and in my environment, the footer is present in both cases, even if I downgrade Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation from version 6.0.1 to 6.0.0.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and can reproduce the OP. As soon as you add `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()` the scoped css classes stop being rendered and you loose the bootstrap footer style, which makes it go up the page and be thin

Answer (score 2):

Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation version 5.0.17 Nugget Package cleared the error for me.
You may try to install any version from 5.0.0 - 5.0.17

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no need to add the runtime compilation since in the newest update/version hot-reload has been officially released.

PS. I am currently following an asp.net tutorial and I encountered this problem. Here's the link: https://youtu.be/hZ1DASYd9rk

Answer (score 0):

I'm watching same video series as you do and i had the same error. I upgraded Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation to v6.0.11 and I don't get any error anymore I

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I solved it by adding this CSS in either `Site.cs` or `_layout` file:

in site.css :

```
    body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    }
    .footer {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    margin-top: auto;
    }
```

Or in _Layout.cshtml
in head section add style tag:

```
    <style>
         body {
           display: flex;
           flex-direction: column;
           min-height: 100vh;
           margin: 0;
         }
        .footer {
           border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
           text-align: left;
           padding: 1rem;
           background-color: #f8f9fa;
           margin-top: auto;
        }
    
    </style>
```

and the footer back to a correct position.